# How to sort alphabetically based on a particular column in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, sorting

I was unsure how to word the inquiry.  I have a huge swath of a few thousand entries i'd like to sort alphabetically but using the built-in notepad++ sorts numbers first and in my case, i need a certain portion ignored.  Showing is the only way i know how to explain this.

Here is some example data

```
000500001010a900       1baf3214cb4b7a7b0aeb1b287d2e9d1a       Super Mario Kart                    
000500001010ab00       4e2a55f304b20e1af742bfbc710f5f40       Batman Arkham City: Armored Edition 
000500001010ac00       7092878593502e59e62b3b75de3de8b4       BEN 10 OMNIVERSE™                   
000500001010ad00       34a8f7d901a8e0358377bff9ae13c779       Darksiders II                       
000500001010ae00       b685d174175996dfcef21b6a14c601b1       JUST DANCE 4                        
000500001010af00       76e7ad38eed475ffbd7b416f49f34fe9       Marvel Avengers™: Battle for Earth
```

as you can see, its sorting based off the numbers, I'd like to sort based off the title.  Easy enough if i omitted all the rest, but I need to keep the title in the same row as the title id and key.  Therein lies my issue.

Comment: I believe what you are asking about it outlined here on this post https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2014/10/15/notepad-column-editing/. Essentially, you will move the column to be sorted to be the first column, and then sort that. Look over the post and take a stab at it.

Comment: if you dont want to change the order of the coluns in your file, a non notepad++ workaround would be to use the CLI (currently not on windows computer - so I can' check the needed powershell commands) - but if you have cygwin you can use `cat <your file name> | sort -k 3 > <new file name>` number 3 is the column you do the sort. and then open the new file in notepad++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Place the cursor before the first character of the desired column.
2. Press and hold the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key.
3. By using the mouse mark the block in the column you want to sort like shown in the screenshot below.
4. From the main menu go to e.g. **Edit > Line operations > Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending** and sort the lines for your needs.

[image]

If you prefer to use the keyboard in step 2 press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> keys and mark the block with the cursor keys.

Comment: Not practical if you have 700k lines.  You cannot go directly to the last line when shift+alt is pressed.

Comment: @Pino Place the text cursor in any of the four corners of the column, scroll using the scrollbar, hold the Alt key while clicking on the opposite corner.

Answer (score 2):

There are more possibilities than the other answer. Particularly, there are much more feasible methods for huge files (for example the "scrollbar" method below). My corrections and additions to the other answer got rejected, saying it should be a separate answer, so here goes:

1. [Select the column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_(user_interface)#Column_selection) by doing one of the following:

   - Click&drag the mouse cursor from one corner of the column to its opposite corner while holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key during some of the dragging.
   - Or place the text cursor in any of the four corners (for example upper left) of the column, and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while moving the text cursor to the opposite corner using arrow keys and/or <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and/or <kbd>PageDown</kbd>.
   - Or place the text cursor in any of the four corners of the column, scroll to the opposite corner (using the scrollbar or mousewheel), and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking on that opposite corner.
2. From the main menu go to e.g. **Edit > Line operations > Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending**.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In which way is it different than other answer?

Comment: The other answer vaguely mentions the mouse, but doesn't explain the two different methods that use the mouse. As you can see in its comments, a reader didn't deduce one of those methods from that vague description. That answer also doesn't let the reader in on the fact that what's going on is the selection of a column called "column mode"/"column selection", whereas I explain that and provide a link to Wikipedia. The alternative method in that answer is mentioned too late (after the alternative is available) and references the wrong step.